# Merge CSV files with field delimiters also occuring inside quotes

Tags: awk, quoting, csv, join

I have 3 csv files I want to join by first column (id column)

Each file has the same 3 columns.

Row example :

```
id        | timestamp       |  Name

3792318, 2014-07-15 00:00:00, "A, B"
```

When I join the 3 csv files with

```
join -t, <(join -t, csv1 csv2) csv3 > out.csv
```

The `out.csv` file doesn't have the same number of columns for each row, probably because the delimiter is a comma and some rows (like in the example above) have commas in the contents of the cell.

Comment: The header is not part of your actual file right? Also, are non-delimiter commas always within quotes?

Comment: The header is for show only, & yes

Comment: Can we safely assume that 1) the 1st field will never contain a comma and 2) You only want the ids that are present in the 1st file (if an id is in file2 and not in file1, you ignore it)?

Comment: CSV is not a simple format, although there are some simple CSV files. You are much better of using a proper CSV parsing library (available e.g for Python and Perl) that transparently take care of (non-)quoted/multi-line/embedded-seperator etc. values.

Comment: terdon, the 1st column never contain a comma, all the rest might contain, and yes I ignore it (its an extreme case)

Comment: Surely whether `"A, B"` gets treated as one column or two depends on the application you are opening the `out.csv` file with? For example, `LibreOffice` by default interprets `"` as a text delimiter and imports `"A, B"` as a single field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, using a csv parser would be better but if we can safely assume that

1. The 1st field will never contain a comma;
2. You only want the ids that are present in the 1st file (if an id is in file2 or file3 and not in file1 of you ignore it);
3. The files are small enough to fit in your RAM.

Then this Perl approach should work:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;

my %f;
## Read the files
while (<>) {
    ## remove trailing newlines
    chomp;
    ## Replace any commas within quotes with '|'.
    ## I am using a while loop to deal with multiple commas.
    while (s/\"([^"]*?),([^"]*?)\"/"$1|$2"/){}
    ## match the id and the rest.
    /^(.+?)(,.+)/; 
    ## The keys of the %f hash are the ids
    ## each line with the same id is appended to
    ## the current value of the key in the hash.
    $f{$1}.=$2; 
}
## Print the lines
foreach my $id (keys(%f)) {
    print "$id$f{$id}\n";
}
```

Save the script above as `foo.pl` and run it like this:

```
perl foo.pl file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
```

---

The script above can also be written as a one-liner:

```
perl -lne 'while(s/\"([^"]*?),([^"]*)\"/"$1|$2"/){} /^(.+?)(,.+)/; $k{$1}.=$2; 
           END{print "$_$k{$_}" for keys(%k)}' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to remove comma inside qoutes ? or replace with other symbol ?

Comment: @JimWest sure, see updated answer. I must stress however, that you would be much better off using a parser designed for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

[TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) language:

```
@(do
   (defun csv-parse (str)
     (let ((toks (tok-str str #/[^\s,][^,]+[^\s,]|"[^"]*"|[^\s,]/)))
       [mapcar (do let ((l (match-regex @1 #/".*"/)))
                     (if (eql l (length @1))
                       [@1 1..-1] @1)) toks]))

   (defun csv-format (list)
     (cat-str (mapcar (do if (find #\, @1) `"@1"` @1) list) ", "))

   (defun join-recs (recs-left recs-right)
     (append-each ((l recs-left))
       (collect-each ((r recs-right))
         (append l r))))

   (let ((hashes (collect-each ((arg *args*))
                   (let ((stream (open-file arg)))
                     [group-by first [mapcar csv-parse (gun (get-line stream))]
                               :equal-based]))))
     (when hashes
       (let ((joined (reduce-left (op hash-isec @1 @2 join-recs) hashes)))
         (dohash (key recs joined)
           (each ((rec recs))
             (put-line (csv-format rec))))))))
```

Sample data.

Note: the key 3792318 occurs twice third file, so we expect two rows in the join output for that key.

Note: The data is not required to be sorted; hashing is used for the join.

```
$ for x in csv* ; do echo "File $x:" ; cat $x ; done
File csv1:
3792318, 2014-07-15 00:00:00, "A, B"
3792319, 2014-07-16 00:00:01, "B, C"
3792320, 2014-07-17 00:00:02, "D, E"
File csv2:
3792319, 2014-07-15 00:02:00, "X, Y"
3792320, 2014-07-11 00:03:00, "S, T"
3792318, 2014-07-16 00:02:01, "W, Z"
File csv3:
3792319, 2014-07-10 00:04:00, "M"
3792320, 2014-07-09 00:06:00, "N"
3792318, 2014-07-05 00:07:01, "P"
3792318, 2014-07-16 00:08:01, "Q"
```

Run:

```
$ txr join.txr csv1 csv2 csv3
3792319, 2014-07-16 00:00:01, "B, C", 3792319, 2014-07-15 00:02:00, "X, Y", 3792319, 2014-07-10 00:04:00, M
3792318, 2014-07-15 00:00:00, "A, B", 3792318, 2014-07-16 00:02:01, "W, Z", 3792318, 2014-07-05 00:07:01, P
3792318, 2014-07-15 00:00:00, "A, B", 3792318, 2014-07-16 00:02:01, "W, Z", 3792318, 2014-07-16 00:08:01, Q
3792320, 2014-07-17 00:00:02, "D, E", 3792320, 2014-07-11 00:03:00, "S, T", 3792320, 2014-07-09 00:06:00, N
```

A more "correct" `csv-parse` function is:

```
   ;; Include the comma separators as tokens; then parse the token
   ;; list, recognizing consecutive comma tokens as an empty field,
   ;; and stripping leading/trailing whitespace and quotes.
   (defun csv-parse (str)
     (labels ((clean (str)
                (set str (trim-str str))
                (if (and (= [str 0] #\")
                         (= [str -1] #\"))
                  [str 1..-1]
                  str))
              (post-process (tokens)
                (tree-case tokens
                  ((tok sep . rest)
                   (if (equal tok ",")
                     ^("" ,*(post-process (cons sep rest)))
                     ^(,(clean tok) ,*(post-process rest))))
                  ((tok . rest)
                   (if (equal tok ",")
                     '("")
                     ^(,(clean tok)))))))
       (post-process (tok-str str #/[^,]+|"[^"]*"|,/))))
```